# Searching to a Map or List

Tags: java, database, gwt, search

I'm deploying my GWT application in a CMS where "data" comes from the CMS "structures" then processed into a Javascript DB (I use TaffyDB).

That JS DB, is processed to be inserted in a GWT map and becomes:

```
Map<Long, Product> mp;
```

Products count will not be so much and that I think browser can handle it. What is the possibility that I can search in this Map for specific `Product` attribute? Then return a `Map` or `List` of `Product`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First trivial approach should be to iterate the Map and get the `Product`s which matches. If that is too slow you can create specialized maps where it is easier (faster) to find the things you are looking for. How these maps looks like depends on your "queries".

For example

```
Map<String, Collection<Product>> colorMap; // maps colors to Products
```

or

```
Map<Integer, Collection<Product>> ratingMap; // maps user rating to Products
```

You should create those initially. So you have to iterate the overall map only once.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the possibility that I can search in this Map for specific Product attribute?

The good news is that this is possible. The bad news is that it will involve a linear-time search. In other words, you'll have to examine every element of the map.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is easy as it was said beforehand

```
List<Product> matchingPrds = new ArrayList<Product>();

foreach(Product pr : mp.Values())
{
    if(pr.getAttribute() == yourValue)
    {
        matchingPrds.add(pr);
    }
}

return pr;
```

Iterating a map is a bad idea though. If you want this done multiple times you could iterate one time save to a new collection.This is not memory intensive as the collections only save pointers, and the object instances are essentially the same.

So depending on the usage you could go with user714965 solution

example

```
Map<String,Map<Int,List<Product>> attrValueProductsMap = new HashMap<String,Map<Int,List<Product>>();
```

Where String is the attribute i.e. width, the int is the value is 300 and the List contains all the products of this Attribute,Int. The types could be diffirent depending on the implementation.